# Traverse through all folders and renaming all files inside folder sequentially 1.*, 2.*, 3.*

Tags: bash, directory, rename, sh

This does not work... I am still rather bad with sh scripts.

```
for imageFolder in *; do
    [ -d $imageFolder ] && cd "$imageFolder" && 
        for file in *.*
        do
          echo "$file" #"${file/?/?}" //the bit I am stuck on I believe.
        done
done
```

I have the following folder structure and I would like all files to start with `1` rather then `0`

[image: name]

So the folder structure would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you will find a `${file/?/?}` parameter substitution that produces a numeric sequence - especially not a per-folder numeric sequence. Instead you will need to set and increment a variable.

What parameter substitution (specifically, `${file##*.}`) *will* be useful for is extracting the file extension, so that you can re-add it to the sequential file name. So for example you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for imageFolder in */; do 
  cd "$imageFolder" || continue
  n=1
  for file in *.*; do 
    echo mv -- "$file" "$((n++)).${file##*.}"
  done
  cd -
done
```

or (with a subshell)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for imageFolder in */; do 
(
  cd "$imageFolder" || exit
  n=1
  for file in *.*; do 
    echo mv -- "$file" "$((n++)).${file##*.}"
  done
)
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steeldriver!! What would be simple with JS is much harder for me in bash :)